# How to remove array element in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to remove barcode from this array.

My dataframe looks like the sample given below,

```
|-- variants: array (nullable = true)

 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |-- admin_graphql_api_id: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- barcode: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- compare_at_price: string (nullable = true)
```

Can you help me to remove the element from the dataframe using PySpark.

Comment: when you remove the `element`, wouldn't you end up with an empty array?

Comment: No, I want admin_graphql_api_id and compare_at_price alone

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didnt see the first line of your post

Comment: No issues @werner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [arrays_zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=explode#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip):

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, StructType, StructField
df = df.withColumn("variants", F.arrays_zip("variants.admin_graphql_api_id", "variants.compare_at_price"))
df = df.withColumn("variants", F.col("variants").cast(schema))
df.printSchema()
```

prints

```
root
 |-- variants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- admin_graphql_api_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- compare_at_price: string (nullable = true)
```

The second `withColumn` is necessary to set the field names of the new struct.

---

`arrays_zip` is only available for Spark version >= 2.4.0. If you are using an older Spark version, you could use an UDF:

```python
def func(array):
    return [[x.admin_graphql_api_id, x.compare_at_price] for x in array]
func_udf = F.udf(func, schema)
df = df.withColumn("variants", func_udf("variants"))
```